# Install Elixir lang on Linux Mint

Tags: software-installation, apt

I've followed the [instructions on the Elixir site](http://elixir-lang.org/install.html) for Ubuntu by downloading and installing their `erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb` but no install target is found when trying to install.

```
$ sudo apt-get install elixir                           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package elixir
```

No matching target in apt-cache

```
$ sudo apt-cache search elixir
elyxer - standalone LyX to HTML converter
libelixirfm-perl - perl implementation for Functional Arabic Morphology
python-elixir - Declarative Mapper for SQLAlchemy
```

Erlang solutions repo in sources

```
$ ll /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
total 12K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 183 Oct 29 23:38 erlang-solutions.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  58 Nov 26  2013 getdeb.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 458 Apr 20  2014 official-package-repositories.list
```

I'm running Linux Mint 16 (Petra) based on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander)

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/erlang-solutions.list
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com/debian saucy contrib

$ sudo apt-get update | grep erlang
Ign http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com saucy InRelease
Hit http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com saucy Release.gpg
Hit http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com saucy Release
Hit http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com saucy/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com saucy/contrib i386 Packages
Ign http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com saucy/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com saucy/contrib Translation-en
```

Not sure why this repo doesn't provide me with an install target for elixir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you could have guessed, the package `elixir` isn't available in anything that isn't Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 14.04 (and probably later) and Debian 7. You can check the [packages list](http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) for Saucy, and you will notice the package isn't there. [Trusty repository](http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) does have it:

```
Package: elixir
Version: 0.13.3-1
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Erlang Solutions <packages@erlang-solutions.com>
Installed-Size: 3291
Depends: erlang-base (>= 1:17.0) | erlang-base-hipe (>= 1:17.0) | esl-erlang (>= 1:17.0)
Section: contrib
Priority: optional
Homepage: http://elixir-lang.org
Filename: pool/elixir_0.13.3-1~ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb
```

What you should do is using one of the supported systems and you will be fine.

Comment: I'll try changing my sources to use the 12.04 package and see if it works with Mint 16. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 16):

I tried too from Elixir's documentation; at first I failed, then eventually installed `elixir` successfully on my **MintDebian1** (Debian wheezy).

I don't really know what's going on. I tend to think they have a typo on their documentation and wrote `apt-get install elixir` instead of `erlang`, because all other blog posts I found that use the same `.deb` do install `erlang` and then install elixir manually.

I went to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/erlang-solutions.list`, changed `squeeze` to `wheezy`, ran `apt-get update` and finally I found `elixir` and all is well.

PS: it is possible to not install Elixir but still run it, and the `iex` repl too, from a Docker image. See https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/nifty/elixir/

Comment: Changing `squeeze` to `wheezy` fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Using LMDE 2, this worked!

Comment: in my case it was changing `Tricia` to `bionic`

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and my system is Ubuntu 14.04, i.e. one of the systems that the Elixir installation link in the question suposedly supports.

The esl-erlang that I installed (as per the Elixir link above) failed to work with a precompiled Elixir binary that I downloaded from github. I therefore purged that erlang install (`sudo apt-get purge esl-erlang`) and went to the [Erlang installation web page](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html), which also has a tab for Elixir.

I first followed the alternative Erlang OTP instructions; I added the appropriate line to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then manually adding the public key. Finally, after running `sudo apt-get update`, I successfully installed both esl-erlang and elixir.

I am now running `iex` successfully.